# Attribute not working

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to get stock market history using pandas-datareader
i  install pandas-datareader by pip install pandas-datareader

here is my code which i am trying to get data

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from  pandas_datareader import data, wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from  matplotlib import style


style.use('ggplot')


start =datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)

end = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)

df = wb.DatarReader("XOM",'yahoo-dividends',start,end)

print (df.head())

df['Adj Close'].plot()

plt.show()
```

but i get error which say

```
 AttributeError: module 'pandas_datareader.web' has no attribute 'DataReader'
```

Comment: Try uninstalling the 'pandas_datareader' and re-installing it.
    `pip uninstall pandas-datareader`
    `pip install pandas-datareader`

Comment: Thax @10101010 as you said i already tried this but still its not working

Comment: Do you have any file named `pandas_datareader` in your current directory. Perhaps you are referring to that file.

Comment: Replace `wb.DatarReader` to `data.DataReader`. You have a typo and also `DataReader` is an attribute of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Your import statement is wrong, change it to `from pandas_datareader import data, wb`

There is a great answer about modules and packages here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111882/246262

Comment: thanx @vinny  yes i changed my import statement but still i get same error

Comment: i changed it from import pandas_datareader.data as wb to from pandas_datareader import data  , wb

Comment: Your error prints `pandas_datareader.web`. Double check it is pandas_datareader only